# Syntax error on return statement

Tags: php, mysql, function, syntax-error

I'm doing this simple website, and I have run into this error:

My function:

```
<?php 
function user_exists($username)
{
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return (mysqli_result($query, === 0) 1) ? true : false;
}
 ?>
```

My php error log:

```
PHP Parse error:  
syntax error, unexpected '===' (T_IS_IDENTICAL) in function on line 6
```

Line 6 is the return line.

I understand what a syntax error means, but I'm quite sure that the `'==='` is not the problem.

Comment: The === is the problem. What is that return trying to do? The mysqli_result call is badly formatted - the second parameter is `=== 0`, which isn't correct.

Comment: Do not try to sanitize user input, but use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) instead.

Comment: FYI, there's no such function as `mysqli_result()`. Not all `mysql_XXX` functions have a corresponding `mysqli_XXX` function, and this is one that they didn't copy.

Comment: `($query, === 0)` .  You can't pass `=== 0` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : I was only talking about the ternary condition and this answer is false because the `mysqli_result()` function doesn't exist.

I guess you are trying to do this :

```
return mysqli_result($query) === 0 ? false : true;
```

And as Marcel Korpel said, use prepared statements to avoid security flaws.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the exact thing i was trying to do!

Comment: This will not work because `mysqli_result()` does not exist, and even if it did, that would be the wrong syntax. It would be `mysqli_result($query, 1)`

Comment: I didn't check the function, and I should have. All I saw was a bad use of the ternary condition, and I thought it was the only problem. As MrCode said, it won't work and you should look for another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here. First of all there is no `mysqli_result()`, it does not exist. Instead you can fetch the row like below. Also your `$connect` is out of scope. You need to pass it as an argument, and as the comments point out even if `mysqli_result()` did exist, it still wouldn't work because of the syntax error.

```
function user_exists($username, $connect)
{
    $output = false;
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");

    if($query) // check the query was successful before trying to fetch
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $output = $row[0] > 0;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

I assume your `sanitize()` is doing `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. For best security, switch to a [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Thank you for your long comment! It was very useful, i will definitely look into prepared statements.